# How to get ISO week numbers from date

Tags: r

I would like to get the ISO week number from a given date in string format, where Monday is the first day of the week, and the week that contains the first Thursday of the year is considered to be the first week.

From other answers, I think `strftime("2017-11-18", format = "%V")` suits my purpose the best.
However it doesn't work on Windows.

Any suggestions for alternatives with only the base package in R?

Comment: Update: the "%V" format string is widely supported since R 3.1.0, even on Windows. No need for alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the package `lubridate`

it has a function `isoweek()`which gives you the ISOWeek of a given date

```
lubridate::isoweek("2017-11-18")
[1] 46
```

Now you just want to use the base packege. Here ist the code from lubridate for the ISO week

```
function (x) 
{
  xday <- make_datetime(year(x), month(x), day(x))
  dn <- 1 + (wday(x) + 5)%%7
  nth <- xday + ddays(4 - dn)
  jan1 <- make_datetime(year(nth), 1, 1)
  1L + as.integer(difftime(nth, jan1, units = "days"))%/%7L
}
```

we can take that an make it to something which only uses the base package.

```
myIsoweek <- function (x) 
{
  dateList <- as.list(strsplit(as.character(as.Date(x)),split = "-")[[1]])
  names(dateList) <- c("year","month","day")

  weekday <- as.POSIXlt(x)[["wday"]] + 1

  xday <- ISOdate(dateList$year, dateList$month, dateList$day)
  dn <- 1 + (weekday + 5)%%7
  nth <- xday + 86400*(4 - dn)
  jan1 <- ISOdate(format(nth,format = "%Y"), 1, 1)
  1L + as.integer(difftime(nth, jan1, units = "days"))%/%7L
}
```

Comment: It has the same license as R so if you can't use that license then you can't use R either.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck That's true, but we are using TERR here.

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` has an implementation of `isoweek` which you might want to just port (it's easy to replicate with `base` functionality)

```
# data.table approach:
isoweek <- function(x) {
  x = as.IDate(x)   # number of days since 1 Jan 1970 (a Thurs)
  nearest_thurs = as.IDate(7L * (as.integer(x + 3L) %/% 7L))
  year_start <- as.IDate(format(nearest_thurs, '%Y-01-01'))
  1L + (nearest_thurs - year_start) %/% 7L
}
```

Ported to be strictly `base`:

```
isoweek <- function(x) {
  x = as.Date(x)   # number of days since 1 Jan 1970 (a Thurs)
  nearest_thurs = as.Date(7L * (as.integer(x + 3L) %/% 7L), origin = '1970-01-01')
  year_start <- as.Date(format(nearest_thurs, '%Y-01-01'))
  1L + (nearest_thurs - year_start) %/% 7L
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `strftime("2017-11-18", format = "%W")` should work in Windows.

Comment: Hi Cihan, I've tried %W, it doesn't give the ISO week. I saw in it's documentation it mentions "first Monday of the year as day 1 of week 1"

Comment: You are correct.   Can you try `format(as.POSIXct(as.Date("2017-11-18")),  "%V")` instead? I've found a discussion that's on this topic here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Match-ISO-8601-week-of-year-numbers-to-month-of-year-numbers-on-Windows-with-German-locale-td4728059.html

Comment: It returns the same empty string for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Python datetime library has a native function for getting ISO year, week number and week day: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar. It returns a tuple with all three values, so just select the second element if you want to have the week number only.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime

// Create a datetime object from your string
my_date = datetime.strptime('2017-11-18', '%Y-%m-%d')
// Get the tuple of ISO date values from your datetime object
my_iso_tuple = my_date.isocalendar()
// Get the ISO week number
my_iso_week_number = my_iso_tuple[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
format(as.Date("2017-02-015"),"%W")
```

Comment: Hi Smiley, this only give the day of the week instead of the week number. Also it use Sunday as first day of the week.

Comment: Hi noname, sorry i meant the capital "W" but still it wouldn't help you answer with the need of  monday to be first day of the week.

Comment: If there is really no way, you can consider using cut() function to manually define your own customized week